# After `M-x pdb` switch to `compilation-mode` automatically?

Tags: python, debugging, compilation-mode, gud

`M-x pdb` is great while debugging.  When the python process exits though, often there is a traceback left behind in the `gud` buffer that I'd like to view using `compilation-mode` so I can use `next-error` to step through the stack frames.

I can always `M-x compilation-mode` on python exit.  Can I have emacs automatically do that for me?

Comment: In realgud (available from MELPA), the way this is handled is that there is a function realgud:goto-lang-backtrace-line bound to C-C ! !  So you just position yourself on the traceback line and that enter C-C !! and the location will come up in another bugger.

Comment: Another what?  This is more than 15 characters long.

Comment: bugger->buffer (or rather buffer window in the same display).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(defun my/turn-on-compilation-shell-minor-mode ()
  (compilation-shell-minor-mode t))
(add-hook 'pdb-mode-hook #'my/turn-on-compilation-shell-minor-mode)
```